# Alternative reasons for Low Quality Posts need more highlighting if they exist

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

Currently the review-beta Low Quality Posts page says:

> This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**.

Because these seem to be the reasons for (almost?) all low-quality posts, any different reasons need to be more than just bold.

Specifically, just *after* clicking "Looks Good", as it fades away I occasionally get the feeling I've missed alternate reasons...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what other reasons do you think there might be?  The time of day? The poster's username? It seems to me that "content" is a pretty all-encompassing reason.

Comment: It was just a feeling that it was occasionally a different reason. I fully understand _now_ it is likely this is not the case.